# how to enable multiple calls to non xa datasource in a transaction jboss 6

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, jta, jboss6.x

In one of our timer ejb we calls to 2 non xa datasources in jboss 6 and we get the following error.

> *[org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http-0.0.0.0-443-4) Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object!; - nested throwable: (javax.transaction.SystemException: java.lang.Throwable: Unabled to enlist resource, see the previous warnings. tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff0ab1ded5:1396:544f790a:1842 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >); - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object!; - nested throwable: (javax.transaction.SystemException: java.lang.Throwable: Unabled to enlist resource, see the previous warnings. tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff0ab1ded5:1396:544f790a:1842 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >))*

There are advice's to modify the  jbossjta-properties.xml to include the following, but this also did not work as jboss 6 doesn't have this file.

```
<properties depends=”arjuna” name=”jta”>
<property name=”com.arjuna.ats.jta.allowMultipleLastResources” value=”true”/>
```

Please let us know on how to enable multiple non xa datasources in a transaction in jboss 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some googling i found that adding the following property in `transaction-jboss-beans.xml` present in the deploy folder of JBoss 6 for `CoreEnvironmentBean` bean did the trick.

`<property name="allowMultipleLastResources">true</property>`

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to set this with `jboss-cli` ?